# Differential Inverse Kinematics Integrator does not work with a floating plant

Tags: drake

**Drake version: Dockerhub latest (1.14.0) Python 3.8, OS: Ubuntu 20.04**

Differential inverse kinematics integrator LeafSystem demands that the number of positions and velocities are equal, and that they are both equal to the plant’s number of positions and velocities (Lines [123](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/inverse_kinematics/differential_inverse_kinematics.cc#L123), [124](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/inverse_kinematics/differential_inverse_kinematics.cc#L124), and [128](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/inverse_kinematics/differential_inverse_kinematics.cc#L128). When using a floating plant, a floating quaternion joint is introduced to represent the floating element. Floating quaternion jointss, however, are represented in XYZ for position and a quaternion for rotation (7 states). While velocity is represented as XYZ for position and RPY for rotation (6 states). This results in a vector size mismatch error, as depicted by the attached code’s output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

  File "./scripts/diki_floating_isolated.py", line 352, in <module> 

    main() 

  File "./scripts/diki_floating_isolated.py", line 298, in main 

    diki = DIKI(plant, model, euler_integr_time_step, tip_frame) 

  File "./scripts/diki_floating_isolated.py", line 139, in __init__ 

    self.builder.Connect(self.diki_derivative.get_output_port(), self.desired_system_state.get_input_port(1)) 

RuntimeError: DiagramBuilder::Connect: Mismatched vector sizes while connecting output port dudt of System discrete_derivative (size 14) to input port u1 of System multiplexer (size 13)
```

If the signal dimensions are manually trimmed down to match, the output error is:

`Failure at multibody/inverse_kinematics/differential_inverse_kinematics.cc:128 in DoDifferentialInverseKinematics(): condition 'num_positions == num_velocities' failed.`

Other approaches attempted were to intercept the plant’s  state at multiple points along the process and convert between quaternions and RPY and vice-versa, but any state modifications made violated one of the demands regarding position and velocity counts in the integrator.

**Is there a recommended approach to accomplish this that we are missing? The goal is to use the Differential Inverse Kinematics Integrator on a floating iiwa.**

Comment: It would not be hard to generalize the DiffIK implementation to support floating bases, and it would be a nice improvement. I can take a look soon... or we would welcome your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

I've gone ahead and added the missing feature. Drake's differential inverse kinematics codes should support floating bases (and more generally, systems where the number of positions does not equal the number of velocities) once this PR lands:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19522

Comment: Thanks for your prompt help on this Russ! I'm tracking the PR you made.